# JavaScript PriorityQueue.front().element[0] problem

Tags: javascript, priority-queue

Does anyone know why in line "if(nums1[i] + nums2[j] > maxHeap.front().element[0]) break", the front().element[0] expression is not working in JavaScript? How can I access the first value in the maxHeap.front().element? Thank you so much for your help.

```js
const kSmallestPairs = function(nums1, nums2, k) {
  let maxHeap = new MaxPriorityQueue({priority: v=>v[0]})
  
  for(let i = 0; i < Math.min(k, nums1.length); i++){
      for(let j = 0; j < Math.min(k, nums2.length); j++){
          
          if(maxHeap.size() < k)
          maxHeap.enqueue([nums1[i] + nums2[j], i, j])
          else{
              if(nums1[i] + nums2[j] > maxHeap.front().element[0]) break
              else{
              maxHeap.dequeue().element
              maxHeap.enqueue([nums1[i] + nums2[j], i, j])
              }
          }
      }
  }
  
  let result = []
  maxHeap.forEach(a => {
      result.push([nums1[a[1]], nums2[a[2]]])
  })
  
  return result
  
};
```

```js
Line 16 in solution.js
              if(nums1[i] + nums2[j] > maxHeap.front().element[0]) break
                                                      ^
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'element')
    Line 16: Char 55 in solution.js (kSmallestPairs)
    Line 46: Char 19 in solution.js (Object.<anonymous>)
    Line 16: Char 8 in runner.js (Object.runner)
    Line 33: Char 26 in solution.js (Object.<anonymous>)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
```

Comment: What library are you using for your priority queue?

Comment: LeetCode's PQ library